# How to handle missing value datetime64[ns] dtype column for Python Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime64

If I have data something like this, a missing value in 'Date4' column, its a datetime64[ns] dtype.

- How to handle missing values in this type of situation?
- What if I want to fill it with most_frequent date, how can it be done for the dates?

I have searched for the solution on several websites but couldn't get proper answer yet.

```
   No  Name      Date1      Date2      Date3      Date4
0   1  Per1 2015-05-25 2016-03-20 2016-03-22 2017-01-01
1   2  Per2 2015-06-26 2016-05-22 2016-06-22 2017-02-02
2   3  Per3 2015-09-28 2016-07-24 2016-07-26 2017-05-22
3   4  Per4 2015-11-21 2016-09-02 2016-05-09 2017-05-22
4   5  Per5 2015-12-25 2016-11-11 2016-11-14        NaT
```

Comment: Don't post the image of data, post the sample data as text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [135]: df
Out[135]:
       Date4
0 2017-01-01
1 2017-02-02
2 2017-05-22
3 2017-05-22
4        NaT

In [136]: df["Date4"].replace(np.nan, df["Date4"].mode().iloc[0])
Out[136]:
0   2017-01-01
1   2017-02-02
2   2017-05-22
3   2017-05-22
4   2017-05-22
Name: Date4, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was trying with fillna method : df['Date4'] = df['Date4'].fillna(df["Date4"].mode()) like this. But I didn't use .iloc[0], that was the mistake and I got the solution from your code. Now fillna is also working like this : df['Date4'] = df['Date4'].fillna(df["Date4"].mode().iloc[0]) . Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you suggest what other methods can we use to fill missing values in datetime[ns] datatype?

Comment: There are several methods like bfill, ffill but it mostly depends on the data you are dealing with

Answer (score 1):

What you just described is called **Imputation**. Sklearn's [`SimpleImputer()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html) does the job well. You can even specify how you want the missing values to be filled.

```
imp=SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy = 'most_frequent')
df=pd.DataFrame(imp.fit_transform(df))
```

Comment: SimpleImputer does not support datetime64[ns] data type. Otherwise mostly I use SimpleImputer only.